# Equivalence of two definitions of Sobolev spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Good morning,
I am looking for a reference about the following fact that seems to be folklore. Define the Sobolev (Beppo Levi?) space
$$
D^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N) = \left\{ u \in L^{p^*}(\mathbb{R}^N) \mid \nabla u \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^N) \right\}.
$$
Where can I find a (complete) proof that $D^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ coincides with the closure of $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$ under the norm
$$
\|u\|^p = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |\nabla u|^p ?
$$

Comment: What is $p^*$, a typo?

Comment: A standard reference is the book "Sobolev Spaces" by Adams (and Fournier). You can get this by proving the Sobolev inequality for a compactly supported smooth function, where the constant in the inequality depends only on $n$ and $p$ (and not the support of the function).

Comment: $p^* = np/(n-p)$.

Comment: I guess the matter here is exactly to avoid arguments like "this follows easily by adapting..." The OP probably needs a book (or a survey paper) where this characterization is proved. Actually it seems hard to find such a reference.

Comment: The Sobolev inequality (or embedding theorem) shows that if $1 \le p < n$, $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset L^{p^*}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, where $p^* = np/(n-p)$ and therefore $W^{1,p} = D^{1,p}$. The Meyers-Serrin paper below shows that $W^{1,p}$ is equal to the closure of $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with respect to the norm given by the $L^p$ norm of the gradient. Could you clarify what aspect of this you want a proof for? Or is it something else?

Comment: @DeaneYang It seems to me that the OP wants a piece of bibliography. For example "See this book, Theorem X, page Y".

Comment: Aka "H=W" (definition by density vs definition by weak derivative).

Answer (score 2):

I guess the theorem you are searching for is the theorem by Meyers-Serrin, see

http://www.pnas.org/cgi/reprintframed/51/6/1055

The norm you are using is a bit different, but you can easily prove the equivalence of the topologies using the Poincare-Inequality.

Comment: I thought the OP's question was more to do with the density part of the statement: the first definition is an "all objects with finite norm" and the second is "closure of some nice space of well-behaved objects wrt an equivalent norm"

Comment: The question appears to be about the decay of the function at infinity.

Comment: No, I don't think this answers my question.

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is?

Comment: If I am allowed, I'd say the @Paperino does not want any sentence like "but you can easily prove".